# How do I backup the followers of a user on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

I need to download all the followers of a user on Twitter, then download all the followers of each follower (second level network).
I need the data in any format.
Is it possibile? What would you use?

Comment: I would use the [Twitter API reference](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) and a programming language which has libraries that can do HTTP-requests and OAuth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [twitter module](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) for python for example. You will need to [register an appliction](https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new) and to use oAuth. Bad news: also if you prefere something else than python, you will have to use OAuth. Good news: to use the twitter module in order to get information is quite simple afterwards.

**Update:** You can also use supertweet.net if you don't want to mess around with OAuth!

Answer (score 0):

You can use www.TWEXLIST.com. A a recent solution to export any  Twitter list (public or  private), followers list, followings list of  any Twitter account (yours  or any others) in an Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I used Tweetake website to backup my Twitter data but it was closed (https://twitter.com/NikkiPilkington/status/270080732582522880). Since then I realized that it is not good to rely on a third party website and it is better to have a "do it yourself" solution. So I created a script that everybody will be able to use in their browser.

The script allows you to backup Twitter favorites, following and followers: https://gist.github.com/baptx/1525f338d93fa01db4e0
It is written in JavaScript and will create a textarea element with your backup data that you can copy/paste in a file.
You can run it in a browser console on a local web page like Firefox's `about:` or a web page like https://duckduckgo.com/html (in the past I used it directly on https://api.twitter.com/1.1 web page but it's not working any more because they added Content Security Policy).

Before using the script, you need to get your access keys to use Twitter API 1.1: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/application-owner-access-tokens

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.followers-backup.com/web to download the list of followers/following (first level network) of any profile you want and it's free. Give it a try